# A simple php script error result with tables

Tags: php

Hello guys i'm in need of php experts advice.
Here's my problem. A user has 2 inputs the start and the end this are all integers. this will able to identify odd and even. i have solve already odd and even and almost done. main problem ex. start value 1 end 5. 1 is odd it should be displayed on odd in table. but the problem is it is found in even table. initial value is the problem. the rest was good.

here's my code

```
<?php
$firstnum = $_POST['first_input'];
$secondnum = $_POST['second_input'];
$counter = 0;
echo "<table border='1'>";
if ($firstnum < $secondnum) {
    echo "<tr>"; //first tr
    echo "<th>"; echo "Even numbers"; echo "</th>";
    echo "<th>"; echo "Odd numbers"; echo "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    for ($counter=$firstnum; $counter <= $secondnum ; $counter++) { 

        if ($counter % 2 == 0){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $counter; 
            echo "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>";
            echo $counter; 
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

} elseif ($firstnum > $secondnum) {
    # code...
    //first num is < second num
    echo "<tr>"; //first tr
    echo "<th>"; echo "Even numbers"; echo "</th>";
    echo "<th>"; echo "Odd numbers"; echo "</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    for ($counter=$firstnum; $counter >= $secondnum ; $counter--) { 

        if ($counter % 2 == 0){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $counter; 
            echo "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td>";
            echo $counter; 
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: sir but my ouput results are all correct. 2 4 are on even column and 3 5 is on odd. but 1 is on even. the left colum should all be even right column is odd

Comment: check your resulting html source code and you will see that you have invalid html/table code. It is by luck that the evens/odds after `1` ended in the correct column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is you have invalid html resulting from your `if`/`else` blocks.

If your `if` you have

```
<tr>
    <td><td>
```

and in your `else` you have

```
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

Both of these need full row/cell tags

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

So your code should look like

```
    if ($counter % 2 == 0){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $counter; 
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>"; 
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $counter; 
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```